# Array index out of range in tableView

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview

Hello friends I'm trying to complete an application that it's on youtube. Some things have changed in Xcode. The problem is the follow:

I created two variables of type array and I initialized them into a viewDidLoad

var names : [String]?
    var colors : [UIColor]?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    names = Array()
    colors = Array()
}
```

Then I maked a segue to bring data from a view. This work right because I maked tries by console:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let identifier = segue.identifier
    if identifier == "CreateColor"
    {
        let createColorViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CreateColorViewController
        createColorViewController.delegate = self

    }
}
```

This function bring a string and a color (I try the segue with this):

```
func createColor(name: String, color: UIColor) {
    names?.append(name)
    colors?.append(color)
}
```

Then this function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 1
}
```

Then this function of tableview:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellId") as? UITableViewCell

    if cell == nil
    {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "CellId")
    }
        cell?.backgroundColor = colors![indexPath.row]
        cell?.textLabel?.text = names![indexPath.row]

    return cell!
}
```

The problem is that in the video this code work good. But to me, Xcode show me "Array index out of range". I tried initializing both arrays with a any valor and the app run ok, but when I go to the tableView where it get the name and color and come back to the table, it doesn't bring nothing.

I really want to know what's happening :(

The video on youtube is this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_jylonPa8k

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: set ' numberOfRowsInSection ' with your array count

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `colors` & `names` has the same number of objects.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    // return 1
    // must be your dataSource count. 
    return colors.count
}
```

Comment: That's right, now the error don't appear. But it still without bring me the name and color to the table :(.

Comment: Have you check your `names` and `colors` make sure its not nil. and contains the data that you need.